# SIGSEGV (Segmentation Fault) in C

Tags: c, posix, segmentation-fault

I get the SIGSEGV - Segmentation Fault on the run-time for the code below when the function (`log_msg_send`) is called. I read that it is about memory violation but I could not find the reason. I would appreciate for the any suggestions/help.

```
 #define  MAXSTRINGLENGTH 128
#define BUFSIZE 512

void log_msg_send(char *message, char *next_hop);

struct routing {
        int hop_distance;
        char sender_ID[16]; 
};

struct routing user_list[40]  =  { [0]={0,0,0,0}};


int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    strcpy(user_list[0].sender_ID,"192.168.001.102");
    char message[1000];
    strcpy(message,"123456123456");
     log_msg_send(message, user_list[0].sender_ID);

    return 0;
}

void log_msg_send(char *message, char *next_hop){
    char *SRV_IP;
    strcpy(SRV_IP,  next_hop);

    if (sizeof(SRV_IP) == 16){
         struct sockaddr_in si_other;
         int s, i, slen=sizeof(si_other);
         char buf[60] ;
         strcpy(buf, message);

        if ((s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP))==-1){
          fprintf(stderr, "socket() failed \n");
          exit(1);
        }

        memset((char *) &si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));
        si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
        si_other.sin_port = htons(33333);
        if (inet_aton(SRV_IP, &si_other.sin_addr) == 0) {
          fprintf(stderr, "inet_aton() failed \n");
          exit(1);
        }

          if (sendto(s, buf, BUFSIZE, 0,(struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen)==-1){
          fprintf(stderr, "sendto() failed \n");
          exit(1);
        }

        close(s);
    }
}
```

PS. For the people who have the SIGSEGV problem. Most [common reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault#Common_causes) for SIGSEV problem: 
 -   attempting to execute a program that does not compile correctly. Note that most compilers will not output a binary given a compile-time error.
 -   a buffer overflow.
 -   using uninitialized pointers.
 -   dereferencing NULL pointers.
 -   attempting to access memory the program does not own.
 -   attempting to alter memory the program does not own (storage violation).
 -   exceeding the allowable stack size (possibly due to runaway recursion or an infinite loop)

Comment: you can use "valgrind" to easily solve this kind of problem yourself.  just install and then run your program as normal, but put valgrind before the program name on the command line.  it will then detect the error and print out a message.

Comment: Voting to close as why isn't this code working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't allocate memory for `SRV_IP`

```
char *SRV_IP;
strcpy(SRV_IP,  next_hop);
```

so the `strcpy` tries to access invalid memory.

```
char *SRV_IP = malloc(strlen(next_hop)+1);
if (!SRV_IP) exit(1);
strcpy(SRV_IP,  next_hop);
```

Then you check

```
if (sizeof(SRV_IP) == 16){
```

but `SRV_IP` is a `char*`, so its size is whatever size `char` pointers have, usually 8 or 4 bytes. You probably meant the length, so would have to use `strlen`.

Comment: maybe you are about to add this, but i guess `sizeof` should be `strlen`.

Comment: @andrewcooke Right. Thanks for the heads-up.